# how to clear jquery.event.drag

Tags: jquery, drag

http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag

when i create a dragbox how to clear a drag?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply unbind any event handlers which were added.

```
jQuery('elements').unbind("draginit dragstart drag dragend");
```